# Why was this question on optimizing the treatment following seborrheic keratosis scaling closed by 1 mod as "requesting personal medical advice"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

The [question](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/18969/43) (which was deleted by Roomba) is:

> Title: After scaling a seborrheic keratosis near the eye, which ointment is effective to reduce scarring?
>
> After scaling a seborrheic keratosis near (< 3 mm) the eye, which ointment is effective to reduce scarring? Typically one uses [Vaseline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaseline) to help reduce scarring, but it is uncomfortable when it goes into the eye.

I believe this is a quite general question for improving the treatment of patients going through scaling a seborrheic keratosis located near their eye. It doesn't strike me as a personal medical advice but instead is a generic question on a typical treatment.

Why was the question closed by 1 mod as "requesting personal medical advice"?

Comment: What was the original Title question?

Comment: The precise wording of questions is important. The quoted question asks: *which ointment reduces scarring after scaling keratosis*, which sounds like a request for medical advice.  Had it instead asked something like: *Vaseline is used to reduce scarring following keratosis.  Is there a substitute ointment that will be less uncomfortable when used near the eye?*, I think it would have been considered acceptable.

Comment: @RayButterworth the question's title was "After scaling a seborrheic keratosis near the eye, which ointment is effective to reduce scarring?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question asks for a drug recommendation, which is clearly medical advice.

I agree with Ray Butterworth's comment:

> Had it instead asked something like: Vaseline is used to reduce
> scarring following keratosis. Is there a substitute ointment that will
> be less uncomfortable when used near the eye?, I think it would have
> been considered acceptable.

That's why I posted a comment the same day you asked the question: in order to give you a chance to edit it. But you ignored my comment; therefore, closed.

The way you fix things like this is by editing the question to fix the problem and then voting to reopen. I thought you knew that.

Comment: Thanks, I fail to see the difference between the two phrasings, aside from the fact that Ray's phrasing focuses on comfort whereas mine focuses on scarring reduction. I view both phrasing as a drug recommendation from a patient standpoint and as a question regarding the optimal treatment from a medical practicioner standpoint. But if Ray's phrasing makes it on-topic, then I'll use it.

Comment: Reposted:  [Vaseline is used to reduce scarring following keratosis. Is there a substitute ointment that will be less uncomfortable when used near the eye?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/q/24141/43)